# Standard File Format for Sharing Location Data

Tags: ios, geolocation, file-format

I am wanting to add support to my iOS application to share location data, basically names and latlong coordinates, via a file format that can be emailed, save to dropbox, and can be opened by my application.

Is there a standard file format to share this information?  I have done some research, and there doesn't seem to be much, a gpx file seems like overkill. I'd prefer to not make up my own format if one already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use vcard format. 
There is a [GEO value type](http://www.viagenie.ca/publications/draft-ietf-vcarddav-vcardrev-00.txt) for this. vCards are easy machine- and human-readable.
Example:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
TITLE:My Geo Point
GEO:37.386013;-122.082932
END:VCARD
```

Alternatively you can use apple vcard format:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iOS 8.1//EN
N:;Current geo;;;
FN:Current geo
item1.URL;type=pref:http://maps.apple.com/?ll=55.369117\,39.079991
item1.X-ABLabel:map url
END:VCARD
```

This vcard may be opened via maps or messages both mac and ios.

Answer (score 0):

Use GPX file format , as below xml format -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
version="1.1" 
creator="gpx-poi.com">
   <wpt lat="53.140450168" lon="-1.55674562972">
      <time>2014-11-28T09:41:05Z</time>
   </wpt>
</gpx>
```